# Android 2.3 WebView Javascript breaks page

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have following question.
My page contains some custom javascript, which adds tags, images etc.
A simplest example which I have is:

```
function handleIMGDown(index, source)
{
  var filename = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  var source_input = document.getElementById("imageLoader" + index);
  var image = new Image();
  image.src=source;

  source_input.parentNode.insertBefore(image, source_input);
  source_input.parentNode.removeChild(source_input);
  return true;
}
```

So when I load image with this, I get:

http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/9141/screenshot1352718777001.png

Can anyone help me to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... seems I found what's wrong.

I made my WebView transparent, and that seems to be the issue. When setting WebView's background color to any other than 0x00000000, problems disappear.

It's still unclear to me, why content doesn't get updated if background is transparent. Seems some lazy developers forgot this xD